# Moving the submit button outside the form in MVC 5 with Partial view

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

In MVC 5,

I have a Dialog for editing.

The Content area is created from a Partial view.

If I have the submit button inside the form in the Partial view it works. But I would like the Save button to be at the button of the Dialog and hence outside the form and Partial view.

The problem is now that the forms data doesn't get posted. How would you fix this?

I have two ideas:
1) Wrap the form outside the Partial view
2) Make a AJAX request and not use the helper, and collect the data from the form somehow? Doesn't feel like the right way.

**Dialog:**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit database connection</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("View");  }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="saveBtnSettings" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Dialog javascript**

```
var saveSettings = function () {
    var url = buildUrl("Edit", "Setting");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        alert('done' + data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus.toUpperCase() + ": " + errorThrown + 'Could not load html. ');
    });
};
```

**Partial view**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Setting", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataSource, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataSource, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataSource, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Partial view - Works with button inside of the form**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Setting", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataSource, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataSource, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataSource, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" /> @* WORKS WITH BUTTON INSIDE OF FORM *@
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Hide the submit button in the view and trigger the submit() from the dialog's save button instead I guess?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can place a submit button outside the form tags by specifying the `form` attribute (HTML5 only)

```
<form .... id="editform">
  ....
</form>

<input type="submit" form="editform" />
```

Note if the submit button has a value attribute, it won't be posted back.

Another option may be to use css to position it.

Comment: Simple and perfect. Just what I needed. The magic part is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Just submit the form using Javascript:

```
function SubmitMyForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="SubmitMyForm()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for: `document.myform.submit();`

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szas4nnv/) adapted form of code from [this page](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml).